# Does something like "Repair move" exist?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, webstorm

Does *WebStorm* provide a feature like *TortoiseSVN* "Repair move"?

This feature can fix renames which can not be assigned, for example when a file is renamed in a branch, this information get lost when integrating the branch back to the trunk. Two files are listed in the Changeset. `fileA -> deleted; fileB -> added`.

When selecting this two files in *TortoiseSVN*, you can "Repair move" and the history of `fileA` is assigned to `fileB`.

Comment: I don't think so. I've just checked IntelliJ IDEA and Webstorm docs and they do not mention a feature similar to TortoiseSVN's *Repair move*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking. So I didn't overlook.